# Exponents Simplification

Tags: exponentiation, rational-functions

I need assistance with simplifying this rational expression. 
The expression is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{29 + 12\sqrt{5}}}.$$

The answer, for reference, is $$\frac{2\sqrt{5} - 3}{11}.$$
 Thank you!

Comment: There's a mismatched parenthesis there...

Comment: Hint: $(2 \sqrt{5}-3)^2 = 29-12\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Thank you for re-formatting the question!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$ 29 + 12\sqrt{5} = 3^2 + 2^2\cdot 5 + 2\cdot 3\cdot 2\sqrt{5} = (3 + 2\sqrt{5})^2 $$

Thus

$$ \sqrt{29+12\sqrt{5}} = 3 + 2\sqrt{5} $$

If you can't easily see this, here's an algebraic approach: Suppose $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$ \sqrt{29+12\sqrt{5}} = a + b\sqrt{5} $$

Squaring both sides gives
$$ 29 + 12\sqrt{5} = a^2 + 5b^2 + 2ab\sqrt{5} $$

Since $a$ and $b$ are integers, it must be true that
$$ a^2 + 5b^2 = 29, \ 2ab = 12 $$

Solving this gives $(a,b) = (3,2), \ (-3,-2)$. We pick the solution pair that satisfies $a + b\sqrt{5} > 0$, which is $(3,2)$

Comment: I see where you are going, but I don't understand the step where you describe that "since a and b are integers, it must be true that..." Why do we set the first two terms of the polynomial equal to the 29 and the other term equal to 12? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no simpler way to simplify a square root inside a square root. Not all expressions of the form $\sqrt{a + b\sqrt{k}}$ can be simplified.

Comment: I would start with $29 + 2\cdot 6\sqrt{5} $ and systematically choose $a$ and $b$ from factors of $6$ and use trial-and-error to find a pair that satisfies $a^2+5b^2=29$. Usually these numbers are small so you only have a few choices.

Comment: Something like

$$ b=1,\ a=6\to a^2+5b^2 = 41 $$
$$ b=2,\ a=3\to a^2+5b^2 = 29 $$
$$ b=3,\ a=2\to a^2+5b^2 = 49 $$
$$ b=6,\ a=1\to a^2+5b^2 = 181 $$

Obviously you'd stop on the second guess, but at most there are 4 possibilities

Comment: From the simple fact that $\sqrt{5}$ is irrational, so its coefficients have to match. An integer multiple of $\sqrt{5}$ plus an integer, cannot equal any other integer of $\sqrt{5}$ plus a different integer

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! However, where do you get the 11 from? When I squared the denominator, I got 121. Thank you!

Comment: Show your work. What did you do to get 121?